# File descriptors in C. Lugging them around vs static global

Tags: c, variables

If I'm writing a library that uses a file descriptor for doing stuff, when should I return it from `lib_init()` for the higher layer code to use and pass to my `lib_do_stuff()` calls, and when can I leave it as a private "member" in my C library as a static global in .c file?

If I don't think the user of my library should have control or even access to the file descriptor, can I just leave it, much like in C++ it would just be `private`?

What are the downsides for doing it either way?

Comment: As a general advice, you should *never* use static global variables. Instead I suggest you create a "black box" structure which contains all needed variables as members, and return a pointer to that from your initialization function. Much like the C standard I/O functions works, with e.g. `fopen` returning a pointer to an undefined `FILE` structure.

Comment: In what way can I define all my needed internal variables as members in C?  To me that means they are available to the entire translation unit, but not able to be externed.  That's pretty much a static global variable, right?

Comment: That's the nice thing about "black box" structures, you can add new members, delete old, or change existing as needed without worrying that the users of your API will ever notice.

Comment: Do you mean literally returning a pointer to a `struct` from the init function?  I'm still not 100% on your page in terms of actual semantics.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding my suggestion with an example.

Your library needs two (at least) header files: One public that the users of your library includes, and one private that you include only in your library source files.

The public could be something like

```
#pragma once

// This is all that is needed to declare pointers to the internal structure
typedef struct internal_structure STRUCTURE;

// The public API of your library
STRUCTURE *lib_init(void);
void lib_cleanup(STRUCTURE *s);
...
```

Then you have the private header file

```
#pragma once

struct internal_structure
{
    int fd;
    // Other members as needed
    ...
};

// Possible function prototypes of private functions
```

Then in your library source files you include both the public and the private header files, and use `STRUCTURE` for the black-box structure:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "public.h"
#include "private.h"

STRUCTURE *lib_init(void)
{
    STRUCTURE *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
    s->fd = open(...);
    // Other initialization
    ...
    return s;
}

void lib_cleanup(STRUCTURE *s)
{
    // Other cleanup
    ...
    close(s->fd);
    free(s);
}
```

Then the users of your library includes only the public header file, and uses your well-defined API:

```
#include "public.h"

int main(void)
{
    STRUCTURE *s = lib_init();
    ...
    lib_cleanup(s);
    return 0;
}
```

The public functions should all take `STRUCTURE *` as one of their arguments, typically their first argument, similar to the `lib_cleanup` function. The function can then use the structure and its members any way they want.

Comment: Wait, so now I have twice as many header files for each source library file, you suggest putting "//Possible function prototypes of private functions" in a header file that anyone could use, which... uh... misses the point.  A user has access to my internal variables.


Maybe I've been working on too many web applications so I'm in the wrong mindset, but when I imply that I would like to have "private members", I don't mean just writing more convoluted code, or security through obscurity.

Comment: @justynnuff Yes you have twice as many header files as before, but only ***two*** header files in total, not one per source file. Or do you mean you have to `#include` two header files in every library source file? Then yes you do. But that's a small price to pay IMO, especially if that's the only downside you can think of.

Comment: @justynnuff Also, you don't install the private header file, you keep it ***private***. And this is a very common pattern, it's not "security through obscurity" (at least not if you're open.-sourcing the library). The code itself is not more convoluted than if you made the whole structure public, which is also very common. And it *is* one of the best way to make library code reentrant and e.g. allowing multiple threads to each have a separate "handle" for the library.

Comment: @justynnuff The proposal in this answer is similar to the `FILE *` structure used by `fopen`, `fclose`, and related file I/O functions. The assumption is that the developer using your library is not the enemy. To put up a firewall to keep the developer out, your `init` function should return a descriptor, which is a small integer that your library internally maps to a structure pointer.

Comment: I'm not really think developers are enemies.  I guess I just believe in proper encapsulation, and that's what I'm searching for here.